Scalar extension of endomorphism ring of representation
I am currently trying to learn representation theory of finite group over an arbitrary field and i stumbled on a statement that seemed very intuitive to me but i could not find a proof of it anywhere.
Given an irreducible representation $V$ over a field $K$ and an extension $L$ of $K$, we have a natural embedding of $\mathrm{End}_{L[G]}(V\otimes_K L)$ into $(\mathrm{End}_{K[G]}(V))\otimes_K L$ $($as $K$-algebras$)$.
I'd like to prove that this embedding is surjective but I am really stuck.
I am not very familiar with tensor products and their properties and maybe there is a very well known fact about them that makes this proof trivial.

$\mathrm{End}_{L[G]}(V \otimes L)$ is the subspace of $\mathrm{End}_L(V \otimes L)$ defined by a system of equations defined over $K$. Now, for any linear system of equations defined over $K$ and any field extension $L/K$, the solutions of the equation over $L$ are generated by the solutions of the equation over $K$.
